# ionic / Angular : ng-repeat first element doesn't appear

Tags: android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Ionic application and i have to deal with a strange issue...

i just want to put a JsonObject array in a list using ng-repeat, my array is good (test on Json checker, it's all good!)

But when i want to use it in my view, the first element of the array doesn't appear...

here's my code:

```js
  $scope.facilities = [];
  dataBaseService.getAllFacilities(function (data) {
    $scope.facilities = data;
    $scope.loading = false;


    console.log($scope.facilities.length);
    console.log(angular.toJson($scope.facilities));
```

```html
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="facility in facilities" href="#/app/facilities/{{facility.number}}">
        {{facility.number}} : {{facility.short_description}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

in my console log i can see 4 elements and the Json is still good :

[image]

But as you can see, the first element of the list is empty...

Any idea?

regards.

Comment: Definitely isn't there in the element inspector?

Comment: Can you show us all your HTML ? It seems like the first element is cover.

Comment: yeah i see it in the element inspector! seem's to be a CSS/HTML problem... i'll check that thx to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was just a header bar that hid the first element of the list...

ok i feel stupid...

```html
    <div class="bar bar-header">
      <ion-spinner ng-show="loading"></ion-spinner>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="facility in facilities" href="#/app/facilities/{{facility.number}}">
        {{facility.number}} : {{facility.short_description}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: I was pretty sure that was your issue :p